# How can I set dark mode in Code::Blocks 17.12?

Tags: codeblocks

I am using **Code::Blocks 17.12** and I want to set the dark mode theme and I don't know how.

Answer (score 10):

First you need to download the themes, download it from Code::Blocks Theme. Then extract it on the desktop. Close the CodeBlocks application before opening CB Share Config. CB Share Config is a tool that installs along with CodeBlocks. It can be found in Program list.

1. Exit CodeBlocks if already opened.
2. Open CodeBlock Share Config
3. Browser Destination Configuration file which is in right side.
4. Select default.conf
5. Browse Source Configuration file which is in left side.
6. Select the downloaded theme.conf
7. Tick all the checkbox that appeared in source configuration file, which is in right side.  (You can use space to tick)
8. Click on Transfer and then Save, and then Close.
9. Now open CodeBlocks, goto Settings>>Editor>>Syntax Highlighting and then Color Themes.

Here, you can change the theme to downloaded one.

Comment: For linux users; it is `cb_share_config` in the terminal